# Regular expression pattern to match adjacent characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm looking for a regular expression pattern that can match adjacent characters in a string in php.

For example if I have the string "1234" I would like it to match and return

```
1
12
123
1234
```

Is this possible with regular expressions in php?

I've tried

```
$testString = '1234';
preg_match_all('/.+/', $testString, $matches);
```

But that just returns the entire string.

Comment: This is what loops are invented for, not regular expressions. Why do you need regular expressions? Do you need to do more?

Comment: Im curious if this can be done using only regular expressions.

Comment: That's good enough a reason I suppose :). It cannot be done by a single regular expression, that's for sure. Not endlessly anyway. `/((((.).).).)/`, then print the groups in the wrong order, starting with group 4.

Comment: @OmarJackman “Can be” != “Should be”.  Yes, it can.

Comment: What is this obsession with using regexp for everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `strrev` trick it is possible >>

***Code:***

```
$s = '1234';
preg_match_all('/(?=(.+$)).?/', strrev($s), $m);
foreach(range(sizeof($m[1]), 0) as $i) print strrev($m[1][$i]) . "\n";
```

***Output:***

```
1
12
123
1234
```

See [this](http://ideone.com/eFAZ9) demo.

---

However you should also go with simple solution without regex >>

***Code:***

```
$s = '1234';
foreach(range(1, strlen($s)) as $i) print substr($s, 0, $i) . "\n";
```

***Output:***

```
1
12
123
1234
```

Check this code [here](http://ideone.com/pVkzf).

Comment: Not sure why this was upvoted. This is a PHP question, Perl code here is not useful. PHP doesn't have "reverse".

Comment: @mega: Yes, I am the downvoter, and I've provided a perfectly acceptable explanation for why. This answer is not useful. PHP doesn't have the features you're using here.

Comment: @mega: Which is by no means similar to what you've done with your "reverse" in Perl.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible? Yes.  Is it reasonable?   Probably not.

Here is a demo in Perl, just to show it can be done with your particular example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -l

my $string = "abcd";

my $pattern = qr{
    ^
    (?=  ( .{1} )  )
    (?=  ( .{2} )  )
    (?=  ( .{3} )  )
    (?=  ( .{4} )  )
}x;

my @captures = ($string =~ $pattern);

print for @captures;
```

Which when run produces this output:

```
a
ab
abc
abcd
```

The PCRE library that PHP uses is perfectly capable of doing that.  But not even I would do it that way.

And as for arbitrary groupings, that becomes even trickier still, requiring a recursive pattern and even more serious magic.  I wouldn’t do that for anything but some sort of extenence-proof sort of programming contest, not for real code that you would hope to maintain, and not get shot for.

Answer (score -1):

No, this can't be (reasonably) done with regular expressions.

That's why loops were invented though. I'm sure it's quite easy to cook something up with a simple `for` loop.

Example:

```
$str = "1234";
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
    echo substr($str, 0, $i+1) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Every man’s level of reasonableness is his own, but I agree that it doesn’t feel natural to use pattern matching for this.

Comment: @tchrist: Some things are globally agreed upon not being reasonable. HTML **can** be parsed with regex as well. Doesn't mean it's a good idea.

Comment: Pretty sure that I’m going on the last person on Earth you need to talk to about [regex-based approaches to parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231382/regular-expression-pattern-not-matching-anywhere-in-string/4234491#4234491).

Comment: @Ωmega: Please don't edit my code if it doesn't contain syntax errors. Also, don't change the meaning of my answer.